# javax.mail from address like "abc@deg-.com" not working

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail.1.4.4 and i have set from address to

```
**MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(session)
mime.from = new InternetAddress(msg.fromAddress)**
```

When i tried fromaddress as "abc@deg-.com" it will be sending below error.

```
    **MAIL FROM:<abc@deg-.com>
501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 501, with response: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax

RSET
250 2.0.0 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending**
```

And in other case like "abc@def.com" it is working properly.

Can anyone has any idea how to allow mail address like "abc@deg-.com"?

Comment: This looks more like the SMTP server is complaining than JavaMail. If the server would allow it (which may not be a good idea, depending on acceptable mail addresses) so would probably also JavaMail.

Comment: "Bad sender address syntax" says it all, really. A domain name part cannot end with a dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deg-.com is not a valid domain name, which is probably why your mail server seems to be rejecting it. According to [rfc-1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), domain name can be only of format

```
<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "

<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>

<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]

<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>

<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"

<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
```

So the last character of domain name (leaving out tld) cannot be `-`, it can only be a letter or a digit.

It's not related to javax.mail, such a domain name should not exist.